# SFDX VCS repository setup with both DX and metadata source

Tags: salesforcedx, git

Is there a best practise how to organize git repository with both dx source format (using unlocked packages) and metadata format? If there would be few projects started with DX source development and the rest "happy soup" code would be still developed in metadata format.

Should these even be in same repository?